# Scroll to top on click on pseudo class

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, pseudo-class

I have a pseudoclass element(:after to be specific), and I want to scroll to top when I click on it. Somehow this does not work...

I tried this:

```
$('.someclass:after').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

And it does not work. When I use just the normal class, it works perfectly:

```
  $('.someclass').click(function () {...});
```

So I assume, the code works, jquery works, but somehow not with a pseudoclass selector. How can I fix this? To use a normal class is not an option, it has to be my :after class selector.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've heard, you can't select or attach events to pseudo elements because they don't actually exist in the DOM. As linked in a comment above, you can change the attribute that the pseudo element displays using Javascript (since you target the parent) but not the psuedo.